Not able to access GPIO pins on my Pi5
So, I've been writing this device driver program in C to access GPIO pins. Whenever I try to install the module onto the board I get an error at gpio_request. The part I'm not able to understand is that I'm. able to access the pins through a test program i wrote in python. Have followed the pin numbering according to the documentation. Can't seem to figure out the problem here.
The code:
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Johannes 4 GNU/Linux");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple gpio driver for setting a LED and reading a button");

/* Variables for device and device class */
static dev_t my_device_nr;
static struct class *my_class;
static struct cdev my_device;

#define DRIVER_NAME "my_gpio_driver"
#define DRIVER_CLASS "MyModuleClass"

/**
 * @brief Read data out of the buffer
 */
static ssize_t driver_read(struct file *File, char *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offs) {
    int to_copy, not_copied, delta;
    char tmp[3] = " \n";

    /* Get amount of data to copy */
    to_copy = min(count, sizeof(tmp));

    /* Read value of button */
    printk("Value of button: %d\n", gpio_get_value(17));
    tmp[0] = gpio_get_value(17) + '0';

    /* Copy data to user */
    not_copied = copy_to_user(user_buffer, &tmp, to_copy);

    /* Calculate data */
    delta = to_copy - not_copied;

    return delta;
}

/**
 * @brief Write data to buffer
 */
static ssize_t driver_write(struct file *File, const char *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offs) {
    int to_copy, not_copied, delta;
    char value;

    /* Get amount of data to copy */
    to_copy = min(count, sizeof(value));

    /* Copy data to user */
    not_copied = copy_from_user(&value, user_buffer, to_copy);

    /* Setting the LED */
    switch(value) {
        case '0':
            gpio_set_value(4, 0);
            break;
        case '1':
            gpio_set_value(4, 1);
            break;
        default:
            printk("Invalid Input!\n");
            break;
    }

    /* Calculate data */
    delta = to_copy - not_copied;

    return delta;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the device file is opened
 */
static int driver_open(struct inode *device_file, struct file *instance) {
    printk("dev_nr - open was called!\n");
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the device file is opened
 */
static int driver_close(struct inode *device_file, struct file *instance) {
    printk("dev_nr - close was called!\n");
    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = driver_open,
    .release = driver_close,
    .read = driver_read,
    .write = driver_write
};

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module is loaded into the kernel
 */
static int __init ModuleInit(void) {
    printk("Hello, Kernel!\n");

    /* Allocate a device nr */
    if( alloc_chrdev_region(&my_device_nr, 0, 1, DRIVER_NAME) < 0) {
        printk("Device Nr. could not be allocated!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk("read_write - Device Nr. Major: %d, Minor: %d was registered!\n", my_device_nr >> 20, my_device_nr && 0xfffff);

    /* Create device class */
    if((my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DRIVER_CLASS)) == NULL) {
        printk("Device class can not be created!\n");
        goto ClassError;
    }

    /* create device file */
    if(device_create(my_class, NULL, my_device_nr, NULL, DRIVER_NAME) == NULL) {
        printk("Can not create device file!\n");
        goto FileError;
    }

    /* Initialize device file */
    cdev_init(&my_device, &fops);

    /* Regisering device to kernel */
    if(cdev_add(&my_device, my_device_nr, 1) == -1) {
        printk("Registering of device to kernel failed!\n");
        goto AddError;
    }

    /* GPIO 4 init */
    if(gpio_request(4, "rpi-gpio-4")) {
        printk("Can not allocate GPIO 4\n");
        goto AddError;
    }

    /* Set GPIO 4 direction */
    if(gpio_direction_output(4, 0)) {
        printk("Can not set GPIO 4 to output!\n");
        goto Gpio4Error;
    }

    /* GPIO 17 init */
    if(gpio_request(17, "rpi-gpio-17")) {
        printk("Can not allocate GPIO 17\n");
        goto Gpio4Error;
    }

    /* Set GPIO 17 direction */
    if(gpio_direction_input(17)) {
        printk("Can not set GPIO 17 to input!\n");
        goto Gpio17Error;
    }


    return 0;
Gpio17Error:
    gpio_free(17);
Gpio4Error:
    gpio_free(4);
AddError:
    device_destroy(my_class, my_device_nr);
FileError:
    class_destroy(my_class);
ClassError:
    unregister_chrdev_region(my_device_nr, 1);
    return -1;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module is removed from the kernel
 */
static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
    gpio_set_value(4, 0);
    gpio_free(17);
    gpio_free(4);
    cdev_del(&my_device);
    device_destroy(my_class, my_device_nr);
    class_destroy(my_class);
    unregister_chrdev_region(my_device_nr, 1);
    printk("Goodbye, Kernel\n");
}

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);

When using error handling im getting an error "insmod: ERROR: could not insert module gpio_driver.ko: Unknown error 517" and dmesg gives "[13252.213223] Hello, Kernel! [13252.213232] read_write - Device Nr. Major: 510, Minor: 1 was registered! [13252.213434] Can not allocate GPIO 4"

this is the first time im posting a question on this page, so im not able to understand what youre asking for. Could you please guide me as to what is required for a better understanding of the problem?

wiil do it, do you happen to know the solution to the problem?

no, I do not have much experience in writing Linux kernel modules

cross posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78452048/not-able-to-access-gpio-pins-on-my-raspberry-pi-5

Why do you think you need a kernel module to access pins. What is wrong with the existing methods?

im learning to write an device driver using kernel modules hence following this method.
